# Upgrading R from 4.1.2 to 4.2.1 under Ubuntu aarch64/arm64 22.04 LTS have unmet dependencies

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, r

I am using **aarch64** Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (jammy), and the default R for the system
is R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie". I tried to upgrade R to the
latest version of 4.2.1 by exactly following the instruction from [Ubuntu Packages For R - Brief Instructions](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) without any luck.

The error message I got is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends r-base
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.2.1-2.2204.0) but 4.1.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.2.1-2.2204.0) but 4.1.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to use `--only-upgrade` option and it's not working:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade r-base
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.2.1-2.2204.0) but 4.1.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
     Depends: r-recommended (= 4.2.1-2.2204.0) but 4.1.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to remove the 4.1.2 version and install 4.2.1 from scratch:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge r-base* r-recommended r-cran-*
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends r-base
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.2.1-2.2204.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.2.1-2.2204.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

However, when I tried to upgrade R from 4.1.2 to 4.2.1 on AMD64 Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (jammy), all commands above worked. Could it be the R binary builds under amd64 (aarch64) repo **jammy-cran** have broken dependencies? Anyone else had the same issue? Should a bug report be submitted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `aarch64` is NOT `amd64` - it's `arm64`.  DO NOT confuse the two.  Are you sure that the repository you're using (PPA or otherwise) does in fact build for arm64?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in order to installR 4.2.* the current supported releases are:

**Jammy Jellyfish (22.04, amd64 only)**
Impish Indri (21.10, amd64 only),
Focal Fossa (20.04; LTS and amd64 only),
Bionic Beaver (18.04; LTS), and
Xenial Xerus (16.04; LTS).

Source: [R-project.org website](https://cloud.r-project.org/)

To check your architecture:

Run `uname -m`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I later noticing that Ubuntu ARM (aarch64) 22.04 is not supported by R 4.2.1 by the time back then.

Comment: Good. You can accept the "solution" if it answers to your question.